# How can I get recurring timestamp in JS?

Tags: javascript, time, timestamp, recurring

I want to get recurring time in timestamp. For example, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00 and so on. Therefore, each day will have a different timestamp for this watch.

How can i do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Do you want the time of day out of a new timestamp, each day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me.

```
// 24 hours format
var array = [[07, 30, 0, 0], [07, 40, 0, 0], [07, 50, 0, 0], [23, 55, 0, 0]]

// An array for storing timestamp
var timestamp = [];

var date = new Date();

function getReccuringTimestamp(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let timeCalculation = Math.floor(date.setHours(...array[i]) / 1000);
    timestamp.push(timeCalculation);
  };
};

getReccuringTimestamp(array);
console.log(timestamp);
```